# Dynamic generated username for meteor app using Accounts

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I would like to create the username dynamically, so if a new user is registrated there is just the need of the name, surname and email.

This is how I set a username for a new created user.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    user.username   = options.profile.name.toLowerCase();
});
```

This brings me - obviously - to the problem, if I want to create a user with the same name. That will result in an error `Username already exists`.
So I'm looking for some ideas how to proceed in this case. Maybe the first character of the surname can be added or an incrementing number at the end.

But for all of this, I don't know where to implement this, as there has to be a loop which is testing the username...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to test against existing users before committing to a username. Let's go with sequential numbers in the old AOL style:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  let baseUsername = options.profile.name.toLowerCase();
  let user.username = baseUsername;
  let i=0;
  while ( Meteor.users.findOne({ username: user.username }) ){ // look for an existing user with the same username
    i++;
    user.username = baseUsername + i.toString();
  }
});
```

You'll want to make sure that your `username` key is indexed, unique in mongodb.

Comment: How do I index keys in meteor?